# Capistrano deploy cant access server ENV variables, but on the server the ENV exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, environment-variables, capistrano

EDIT: I figured it out in the end. Decided to just manually place the master.key on the server in the cap/shared/config and then symbolic link this to each release upon deploy. It works now.

---

I've setup rails credentials on my production environment. I've put the RAILS_MASTER_KEY into the ubuntu ENV. It's stored in .bashrc and .profile.

In IRB on the server I can type the following command and access the secret key `ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY]`

However when I do my Capistrano deploy it tells me it can't find the secret key.

In my rails app I've edited the /config/environments/production.rb to include:

```
config.require_master_key = true
Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base = ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']
```

But the server won't recognise the secret key.

I am not using DotEnv or Figaro.

Error log below.

```
ActiveSupport::EncryptedFile::MissingKeyError: Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /var/www/appn_name/releases/20190429180042/
```

Comment: As explained in the duplicate `.bashrc` set shell variables and `.profile` is a user specific shell initialization script/file. Which works great if you are using SSH to open a shell - but not for Capistrano which is not running in a shell.

Comment: I figured it out in the end. Decided to just manually place the master.key on the server in the cap/shared/config and then symbolic link this to each release upon deploy. It works now.